# Spark streaming to display mongoDB inserted data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I was trying to implement mongoDB spark streaming communication my objective is to connect spark streaming to mongoDB port so when mongoDb insert any data in collections then I want to display that data on spark streaming running console.

I was used following code

```
    val kafkaParams = Map("metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:27017")
    val topics = Set("sometopic", "anothertopic")
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ReadMongo").setMaster("local[2]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))
    val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](
  ssc, kafkaParams, topics)
    val lines = messages.map(_._2)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1L)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
    wordCounts.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and started `nc` as `nc -lk localhost 27017` but it shows error as

> nc: Address already in use

how should I display mongo inserted data in specific collections or how should I read mongo inserted data in spark streaming so further I will create real time application?

***The main thing is here when data insert into mongo collection then spark streaming display inserted data immediately***

Comment: Did you manage to save the streaming data to MongoDB? And which library did you used? I tried Stratio but still no success. Please redirect me to some tutorial or sample project source. Thanks in advance. Cheers :)